# EC2 instance resize or mount to another volume

Tags: amazon-ec2, filesystems, volume, mount

I have very little left on /, but at the same time there are more than plenty on /mnt volume, how can I use the /mnt and have all my stuff move to there?

```
# df -l
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              2064208   1947044     12308 100% /
/dev/sda2            153899044    192212 145889208   1% /mnt
none                    873880         0    873880   0% /dev/shm
```

And also what's /mnt volume (/dev/sda2) for? is it EBS volume? do I got charged for using it if I move my data/binaries over?

Another solution that I am looking at is to resize the default / volume (/dev/sda2) to a bigger size, then the question would be is it possible? legitimate? and free of charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an article for you on how to resize the root EBS volume:

> http://alestic.com/2010/02/ec2-resize-running-ebs-root

I don't recommend using /mnt ephemeral storage except for temporary, unimportant files. The content of ephemeral storage is lost when an instance is stopped or fails.